# 0-N relation using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

thanks in advance for your support.

Im using Entity framework in an mvc5 application.

The way im working with database is:

I create a model class with table atributes for example:

```
 public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }        
    }
```

Then I use Scaffolding system to generate controller and views.
When I have a foreign key in my table I use this:

```
 public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ProviderID {get; set;}

        public virtual Provider Providers { get; set; }
    }
```

Everything is working fine. When I access to the view, tables are being automatically created with relations, keys, foreignkeys properly.

My problem is:

I have an Article table. Each article can be a tool, a consumable, or a machine. But never all of them (one of them must be choosen)
I found that this is a 0 -> N relation and the way to represent in table is the same that 
1 -> N relation but im not sure about this info because its a bit stupid to have unused fields in the table.

Assuming that this is the way to work here is my model class:

```
public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ToolID {get; set;}

        public int? MachineID {get; set;}

        public int? ConsumableID {get; set;}

        public virtual Tool t { get; set; }

        public virtual Machine m { get; set; }

        public virtual Consumable c { get; set; }
    }
```

I added the ? sign to make that fields not mandatory but its not working. 
I generate the scaffolding views and controller. 
When I run the create view to create a new Article. One of the fields is a dropdown menu to select a tool but I cant leave it empty, I have to choose a field.
If this Article is a consumible for example I want to select what consumible but leave tool and machine empty.

Maybe I have to add an empty field in the view in the dropdown list?
In that case how can I do it?. This is the code in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ToolID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: you can create a radio button that binds to new property (that is not mapped), then it's type the radio button change, it will hide all drop downs and show only selected drop down

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

**New Property**

```
[NotMapped]
public string Type { get; set; }
```

**Radio Buttons**

```
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "type-tool", new { @checked = "checked" }) Tool </label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "type-machine") Machine </label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "type-consumable") Consumable </label>
```

**Drop Downs**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ToolId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tools, "Id", "Text"), new { @class = "hidden type type-tool" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MachineId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Machines, "Id", "Text"), new { @class = "hidden type type-machine" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ConsumableId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Consumables, "Id", "Text"), new { @class = "hidden type type-consumable" })
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $("input[type=radio][name='Type']").change(function () {
        $('.type').hide();
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    }).change();
</script>
```

After submitted you get the `Type`, just make other properties null that is not appropriate with the `Type`.

Comment: [NotMapped] means that its "custom" field not bound to the database logic?.  Will be very usefull to me. Thank you !!

Comment: @TxentxoTxentxako, yes it will not be mapped by EF, don't forget to mark as an answer if it helps, but this is not a complete code, you need to manage initial state which radio that is checked or drop down that is displayed first time, manage the postback, etc